# Check CSS title attribute value empty or not

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a table like this and on desktop everything works fine 
Here is HTML:

```
<table class="responsive-table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
            <th scope="col">Title 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Title 4 </th>
            <th scope="col">Title 5</th>
            <th scope="col">Title 6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Title 1:">
                <span>Some title</span>

            </td>
            <td data-title="Title 2:">60</td>
            <td data-title="Title 3">0</td>
            <td data-title="Title 4:">5.0</td>
            <td data-title="Title 5:">
                <button>Add</button>>

            </td>
            <td data-title="Title 6:"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is when I'm on mobile screen and value is not entered, it screws my layout, but when I put something like -, or . everything works fine. Here is picture[image]

Is there any solution how to fix this? Check title attribute value is empty or not? Help please

Also my css is:

```
 td[data-title]:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgba(94, 93, 82, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Try setting minimum-height of cell or row.

Comment: that is cause the `thead` hasn't got any padding

Comment: Besides it's quite strange table, where the first column is table head. Some HTML attributes like `<table>` has builtin CSS attributes like `display: table`. If you want to do something really custom use `<div>` and `<span>` or use first `all: initial` and then add your styles. And for semantics are `aria` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
td[data-title]{ padding: 1rem; }
```

Adjust the value of the `padding` you need.